# How to read ip address of the incoming emails

Tags: php, cakephp, imap

I have set a continuous project for my class which is available online for students and parents can interact with. So I ask students to email their project progress everyday. I use imap to get the info and display it online.

I understand email addresses can be spoofed. How can I find out if the mail really did come from yahoo, gmail or hotmail. Which imap function could i use. i tried this

> imap_headerinfo($inbox, $emails[$x])

But It does not give me ip address of the servers it passed through.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: You verify that by checking the socket that IMAP is connected with.
What's your connection variable?

Example `$connection` or the `connect()` call?

to be fair to **us** helping you, please post all your relevant code. I assume `$inbox` is a hook to the selected inbox and `$emails` is a hook to the email array in the selected inbox? or is `$inbox` your connection handler? if so, `print_r($inbox);`

Comment: @Torxed is the connections handler. $emails[$] is email number..

Comment: `$inbox` is the connection handler?
**Then do:** `print_r($inbox);`

Comment: But this assumes that this code is run on the __server__ uppon arrival of emails, otherwise you would need to check the meta-data of the email itself for 'sent from <hostname>'.. This is stored in the email itself. Try `print_r(imap_headerinfo($inbox, $emails[$x]));` and see what data you can retrieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$mailinfo = imap_headerinfo($inbox, $emails[$x]);
print_r($mailinfo->from);
```

Should give you:
`personal, adl, mailbox, and host`

Any of the following should help you **$mailinfo->...**:
*(For a full reference, check http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-headerinfo.php)*

`->to - an array of objects from the To: line, with the following properties: personal, adl, mailbox, and host`

`->from - an array of objects from the From: line, with the following properties: personal, adl, mailbox, and host`

`->ccaddress - full cc: line, up to 1024 characters`

`->cc - an array of objects from the Cc: line, with the following properties: personal, adl, mailbox, and host`

`->bccaddress - full bcc: line, up to 1024 characters`

`->bcc - an array of objects from the Bcc: line, with the following properties: personal, adl, mailbox, and host`

`->reply_toaddress - full Reply-To: line, up to 1024 characters`

`->reply_to - an array of objects from the Reply-To: line, with the following properties: personal, adl, mailbox, and host`

`->senderaddress - full sender: line, up to 1024 characters`

`->sender - an array of objects from the Sender: line, with the following properties: personal, adl, mailbox, and host`

`->return_pathaddress - full Return-Path: line, up to 1024 characters`

`->return_path - an array of objects from the Return-Path: line, with the following properties: personal, adl, mailbox, and host`

**Why hostname is important:**
[image]

*(Sorry for the shaky image, sitting on a train)*

Comment: imap_headerinfo does give you the host, but I want the ip address.

Comment: Why? Why is the IP relevant? the host is a reversed lookup on the IP upon arriving from the server.
A IP can be changed every 5 seconds in worst case scenario, so when that email arrived.. it might have been sent from one ip.. but the server which it originated from might have changed it's ip during that time so that IP might belong to Olga, poor old grandmother of some kid in texas..

Comment: From a network perspective, the IP is just a state variable.. It's only good for the current now and then..
When you connect to somewhere else to get a log, the IP doesn't say you much because that's in another present time. So you are most likely looking for the reversed lookup on that IP which is, the hostname in the content i referred to :) This is why the e-mail server is designed to verify stuff like this upon arrival and not something you should be trying to do after the mail has been stored on the server already. MX records yada yada yada :)

Comment: Added a description of why you can accept the Hostname as a valid verification on the email data.

Comment: @Torxed What about situation where the mail server has a static ip and   you need to authenticate that the mail actually came from there? That's my current need, and this doesn't really answer whether it's possible or not

Comment: @eric.itzhak you mean when your mail server recieves a e-mail you want to make sure that the mailserver is who he/she claims to be? Do a PTR lookup on the IP upon the connection stage.

Comment: @Torxed I'm querying the inbox using imap, I have no control over the mail server.

Comment: @eric.itzhak Ok so you want to verify what exactly? Example: You connect to gmail, you open your inbox, you retrieve mail #1, and you want to do...? To my knowledge very few mail-servers save the IP from where the mail came from, but almost every mail-server verify the static IP vs hostname upon arrival. You can find some useful information in the headers within the mail-content.. Perhaps there's an IP in there you can resolve to a hostname and verify it's origin.. But very unlikely the mail server saves an IP since it's obsolete after the mail is stored.